# How can I install a different version of sqlite rather that the one provided

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-5

I'm developing various projects using sqlite and it seems that sqlite keeps updating. Like I was using the version 1.0.105.1 in one project and when I install it in another project, i get 1.0.105.2. I tried to create an entity framework and I get this error. 
`an error occurred while connecting to the database. the database might be unavailable. An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred.` 
I want to stick with one version for a while. So how do I install 1.0.105.1 when I'm provided with only 1.0.105.2 in nuget package manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Install-Package System.Data.SQLite -Version 1.0.105.1
```